# Error for View Rendering Route data must contain an item named controller with non empty string value

Tags: sxa

Getting the below error for all the view rendering.I have installed sitecore 9.0 Update 1 version and installed SXA 1.7.1. The controller rendering is working fine .But I am getting this error for the view rendering

```
Error Rendering View: ~/Views/PageStructure/1-column-100.cshtml: Error while rendering view: '~/Views/PageStructure/1-column-100.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
Inner Exception: The RouteData must contain an item named 'controller' with a non-empty string value.
   at System.Web.Routing.RouteData.GetRequiredString(String valueName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName, Boolean useCache)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.InstrumentendViewEngine.InstrumentOperation(String operation, Func`1 findViewFunc)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.InstrumentendViewEngine.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName, Boolean useCache)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.FindPartialView(ViewContext viewContext, String partialViewName, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
```

Comment: Hi @user6685, welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange! We're glad you have joined. A quick review of your question I noticed that there is not much to go on. Please update with which versions of Sitecore and SXA you are using, as well as steps to reproduce what you've done to get this error. I'm guessing there is something custom you have done but your updates could help steer other people in the right direction.

Comment: Can you share the code and the definition of the view rendering? (assuming this is a custom one)?